# How Enable XML-RPC in WP 4.8.2

Tags: xml-rpc

How Can Enable XML in Version 4.8.2 ?
I Want Enable XML RPC Then Connected to it with Programming library 
thx

i can not connect to xml-rpc with https://github.com/abrudtkuhl/WordPressSharp
WordPress Library for .net

Comment: XML-RPC is an API of WordPress core and it is available by default in any WordPress instalation. What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

XML RPC is enabled by default in WordPress since version 3.5, including WP 4.8.2. Here is the more info about it: [XML-RPC Support](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support). If it is not working for you, it is possible that you have some plugin that disables it, and most security plugins have options to do so.